# How to run all modified JUnit test classes?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, junit

I have an IntelliJ project, versioned in git.

How can I run all JUnit test classes, that I have modified since my last commit?

Comment: Playing the devil's advocate here, is there a particular reason why you don't want to just run _all_ your testing code?  After all, simply because you did not change a certain piece of code does not mean that modifying a different class could not have affected the results of that test.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You really have a point with that! Sadly, in my current projects I have thousands of unit test and cannot do that too frequently - but I agree, that would be advisable, whenever possible.

Comment: I suspected this is the case...I've worked at shops before where the entire test suite would take 12+ hours to run...clearly not feasible on a daily basis.

Comment: Having thousands of tests is quite normal, but I suspect that yours take more than a few seconds to run. If you're interested in the added security provided by your tests, you might want to invest into improving your tests (e.g. make them run faster).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is **Changed Files** predefined scope in [Project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html#views) you can use to view all vcs changed files. From there select all JUnit classes and from the context menu create JUnit Run/Debug Configuration which will fill the classes pattern to run automatically.

Comment: Hmm Is there any way to not show the folder structure in that view. It is not feasible for me to shift/ctrl-click. I want to use select all due to the volume of tests files changed. If I include a folder in the selection it does not look like it would work.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is any 'out of the box' solution to this that you can use. However you could script this in a language of your choice, to find the 'files changed in last commit' you can execute

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~
```

`HEAD~` is a reference to the 'penultimate' commit, specifying only one commit reference to the `git diff` command will automatically compare to `HEAD` which is the latest commit.

You could take the output of this and iterate over it, perhaps if your test classes follow a similar naming scheme to your classes to test execute the tests by specifying a pattern for each file?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution would indeed be possible, but I'm looking for something integrated into IntelliJ, so that I can easily browse the test results and for to reuse all IntelliJ configurations (classpaths, etc.).

Comment: I have looked extensively both now and in the past I could not find anything that met this need.

Answer (score 1):

If your stack is composed of GIT and maven
We came up with this shell script that is appended at the end of ours Jenkins Compilation jobs :

```
for s in `git diff --name-only HEAD~`
do
if [[ $s == *".java" ]]; then
  s=$(echo $s | tr '/' '.')
  s=$(echo ${s%.java})
  s=${s/.java/}
  s=${s/src./}Test
  echo "will test : $s"
  mvn -Dtest=$s  -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 test-compile surefire:test
fi
done
```

Explanations :

```
Get the last commited files
for each
 if it is a java file
   convert name (in unix format) to FQN Test class name without extension
   run the maven test target
```

note : ours filenames for test follow the convention of appending `Test` at the end of the class file name. Adapt to your own conventions

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution (and welcome to the community!). This approach is not IntelliJ-specific, but can be used in any IDE/Build environment.

Comment: you'are right @slartidan I did not mention the IntelliJ part : one can launch the above  shell script inside IntelliJ, see : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shell-scripts.html

Comment: @MattVonCoder ty by the inspiration, I modified a bit to concat all classes to run mvn test just once.

Answer (score 0):

This library seems to provide similar functionality: https://github.com/rpau/junit4git

> This is a JUnit extension that ignores those tests that are not related with your last changes in your Git repository.

Answer (score 0):

@MattVonCoder Thank you for the inspiration. I made some modifications, including concatenating all classes to run 'mvn test' just once, along with some other small tweaks.

```
for s in `git diff --name-only`
do
if [[ $s == *".java" ]]; then
  s=$(echo $s | tr '/' '.')
  s=$(echo ${s%.java})
  s=${s/.java/}
  if [[ $s != *"Test.java" ]]; then
    s=${s/src./}Test
  fi
  s=$(echo "$s" | sed 's/.*\.//')
  classes=$classes,$s
fi
done
echo "Will test .." ${classes:1}
mvn test -Dtest=${classes:1}
```