# intellij idea run test for all uncommitted changes only

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

At times we have ~100 java files in uncommitted changes, result of a big refactoring. Some of those are test files as well.

I have 2 related questions here:

1. Is there any way I can run tests for all uncommitted test files ?
2. Is there any way I can run tests for uncommitted test files as well as tests of my uncommitted source files ?

Comment: Run *all* of your tests. What if some of the files that you didn't touch depend on the ones that you did change?

Comment: @chrylis that would be more than my expectations, I am excited to know if IntelliJ supports it.

Comment: @Vipin yes, IntelliJ can run all your tests. Just right-click your test-folder in the project structure and then click "Run tests".

Comment: @Turing85 don’t want to run all tests, that takes lot of time. Thousands of tests.

Comment: Then you have badly designed tests. As @chrylis alrady said: you should run all your tests.

Comment: Actually I have to run all tests now, since all tests are executed in Jenkins after commit I want to run limited set of tests on local machine. I could not understand what is badly designed here ?

Comment: The _purpose_ of your tests is to tell you if something went wrong during your refactoring, and you can't know that unless you run them. Additionally, even thousands of test shouldn't take more than a few minutes to run unless you're being extremely wasteful (like starting up a Spring context for something that should be a unit test).

Comment: I understand there could some problems with application design, probably we need to keep that separate from this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run all modified JUnit test classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136820/how-to-run-all-modified-junit-test-classes)

Answer (score 2):

There is **Changed Files** predefined scope in [Project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html#views) you can use to view all vcs changed files. From there select all JUnit classes and from the context menu create JUnit Run/Debug Configuration which will fill the classes pattern to run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have tool to run the tests within the "uncommitted files" scope.