# How to select and run only tests that are affected by the change set in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know how to select a latest changeset scope for code format in Intellij Idea. Is there a way to select only those unit tests that are affected by some changeset scope? I.e not only to select the tests affected by the change set as was mentioned [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136820/how-to-run-all-modified-junit-test-classes), but select all tests, that are affected by the underlying code, changed within the changeset?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to select just the recently-changed underlying code. Rather, I put a `self.fail("in progress")` at the end of the corresponding unit test. It will obviously fail, and then I can re-run only the failed tests.

Comment: A tricky way, but I haven't find any other better. But I believe IDE can really specify what is changed and have all the needed power for that...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run all modified JUnit test classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136820/how-to-run-all-modified-junit-test-classes)

Comment: @Andrey not at all. So, the affected code outside the test will not change the test code itselt. I'd like to have a scope of Tests affected by the underlying code's change?

Comment: What do you mean by underlying code change? Do you mean run all tests (even not changed) that cover the production code that has been changed? There is no such detection in the IDE.

Comment: Right, I mean it. And that is the thing I'd like to have there.

Comment: @Andrey do you know where I can ask for a feature request for Intellij Idea project?

Comment: You can request a feature at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA But I'm not sure how you imagine IDE could discover such places in your code base.